# Sybase - How to join 2 tables from 2 different server

Tags: sybase, join

I have 2 `Sybase` db like this:
`10.0.0.140:4300/dbA` and `20.0.0.140:4300/dbB`

Now I need to `join` 2 these tables

```
SELECT t1.Id, t1.name , t2.id, t2.value FROM 10.0.0.140:4300.dbA.dbo.table1 t1 INNER JOIN 
20.0.0.140:4300.dbb.dbo.table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

How could I do it with `Sybase` query?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a proxy table in one of the servers, mapping to the table in the other server. Then join the proxy table with the local 'resl' table.